# Paypal IPN message INVALID

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am using django, python and request. When I try to verify IPN message with following code:

```
data = self.request.POST.copy()
data['cmd'] = "_notify-validate"
url = ""

if settings.DEBUG:
  url = settings.PAYMENT['paypal']['sandbox_ipn_endpoint']
else:
  url = settings.PAYMENT['paypal']['live_ipn_endpoint']

self.logger.debug("Let us try to validate IPN message.")

response = requests.post(url, data=data)

print response.text
```

I always get INVALID response on live endpoint. Any ideas why?

Comment: There is a lot you are not telling us which makes it hard to help. Do you get valid responses on the sandbox endpoint? What are the actual URLs & data that are getting composed & sent? Are you managing your live & sandbox identities (keys) correctly?

Comment: Yes, I get valid response on sandbox, yes I get valid responses on sandbox an yes keys are the right one, otherwise I would get authorization error.

Comment: You need to be POSTing the data back to PayPal exactly how you received it.  Need to make sure URL encoding and everything is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I got it done with following code:

```
query_string = self.request.body.decode('ascii')
response = urlopen(url, b("cmd=_notify-validate&%s" % query_string)).read()
```